# How to authenticate to https://tfspreview.com (MIcrosoft-hosted TFS) using Java command line application?

Tags: java, soap, tfs, oauth-2.0, azure-devops

I am trying to access https://tfspreview.com SOAP interface from my command line Java app. Unlike the on-premises TFS services, this one uses Live ID authentication, which makes causes the communication to fail with a 302 redirect to their authentication service. I have no idea how to proceed with authenticating there.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**< tl;dr >**

You can use [Basic authentication](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/home/news/2012/aug-27/) to provide a headless experience to [Team Foundation Service](http://tfspreview.com).  Also, if you're not using the [TFS SDK for Java](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616), it may help you out.

**< /tl;dr >**

Generally speaking, there are three types of credentials that you can use to authenticate, and that determines the mechanism you use for authentication:

1. A Live ID.  As you noted, this requires you to log in to a Windows Live with a web browser and use the resultant OAuth tokens to authenticate.
2. An additional password mapped to your Live ID, which exists for the purposes of Basic authentication.  Instructions for setting up this additional mapping are available in the [August 27 announcement about this feature](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/home/news/2012/aug-27/).
3. A service account.  In addition to the list of users (specified by Live ID), your Team Foundation Service account also has a special user account that it uses for things like build automation and the like.  There is one service account for each Team Foundation Service account and - as the name implies - this is an administrator account.

Let's take a look at each option:

**Live ID**:
Authenticating with a Live ID using OAuth is going to be difficult for your command-line application.  What Visual Studio does here is to open Internet Explorer to [tfspreview.com](http://tfspreview.com), which will ultimately prompt you to enter your Live ID credentials.  At that point, the various OAuth cookies will get set into your web browser.  Since Visual Studio and Internet Explorer share the same underlying HTTP connection mechanism, it can make use of these same cookies.  With a Java command-line client, you don't have that luxury (unless you're writing this exclusively for Windows and want to write some JNI to call the system's HTTP library that is.)

So what are your options?  I suppose it's possible that you could follow the redirect you're given - at which point you will eventually get a login page that you could POST your credentials to and ultimately get an OAuth cookie sent back to you that you could then use for authentication.  But I suspect that this is probably not the road you want to go down, though.  I strongly suspect that there's a healthy dose of JavaScript required to get you logged in.

**Basic Authentication**:
These require an additional step in setup, but are simple and obvious.  There's no reason not to use these.

**Service Accounts**:
Lacking a web browser, though, you *are* able to present a [WRAP token](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238537/OAuth%20WRAP) with your service credentials.  You can view the service credentials for your account using the very helpful [TFS Service Credential Viewer](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-service-credential-viewer/).  With your service account username and password you can create a WRAP cookie to authenticate with.  But at this point, you're authenticating as the service account, not one of your user accounts.

If you don't want to mess with creating WRAP tokens yourself, you can also use the [Team Foundation Server SDK for Java](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29933) to build a connection.  Simply hand your service credentials in as `UsernamePasswordCredentials` when you create a `TFSTeamProjectCollection`.  Even if you don't want to use the API methods against the server, you can get the raw `HTTPClient` from that connection and it will have all the necessary configuration set.  Taking a dependency on the SDK will also benefit you if we add new authentication mechanisms to the Team Foundation Service in the future as the SDK's API should not change dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is quite helpful. It is tempting to go the SDK path if I am able to get the HTTPClient and reuse is later on in SOAP calls. What I am afraid of though is the size of the SDK - it is 18MB big, which is much bigger than the app itself. Is the redistributable part significantly smaller?

Comment: also (stupid Enter key truncated my previous message) - how do I "present WRAP token" when communicating with TFS SOAP? I am not sure how it is supposed to be done. URL parameter? Cookie?

Comment: The TFS SDK is sort of large, I'll admit that.  The SDK JAR itself is 12 MB: a little bit of that is just because TFS has a large platform (source control, work item tracking, build, etc.) but most of it is dependencies.  Given the wide range of Java runtimes we support, we have to include a lot of dependencies.  However there's also native libraries for each platform we support and you can safely delete the libraries for any platform that *you* don't need to support.  That will save a few MB.  But on the whole, yes, it's big.  I'll try to take a look at how we can pare some of that down.

Comment: Frankly, I just need the version control part. Even more specifically, I just need the part where I can retrieve the HTTPClient with properly set up authentication :)

Comment: do you by any chance know the name of the WRAP cookie?

Comment: I was mistaken.  It's in the Authorization header.  eg: `Authorization: WRAP access_token="..."` as per the spec at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hardt-oauth-01

Comment: oh dear, it seems like actually getting the WRAP token from credentials is a bit too much hassle to bother. I will try the SDK route and see what happens

Comment: @user1537794: understandable - why don't we continue this discussion in email - you can find my address in my profile...