# How to authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services with the new basic authentication from a .Net Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops, basic-authentication

I am trying to access https://visualstudio.com (formerly known as https://tfs.visualstudio.com, http://www.tfspreview.com) from my Windows Service written on .NET.

I want to use the new basic authentication but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I found a lot of links to the blog post [Team Foundation Service updates - Aug 27](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/home/news/2012/aug-27/) but it is using the Team Explorer Everywhere Java client for TFS.

Is there a new version of the TFS .NET Object Model to support the basic authentication?

By the way I've successively logged in with the service account. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560568/how-to-authenticate-to-https-tfspreview-com-microsoft-hosted-tfs-using-java) was very useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you need to have at least [Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35774) installed on your machine. It includes an updated `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` assembly with the `BasicAuthCredential` class.

Here's the code to do it, from [Buck's blog post How to connect to Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
                "yourbasicauthusername@live.com",
                "yourbasicauthpassword");
            BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
            TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
            tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                new Uri("https://YourAccountName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"),
                tfsCred);

            tpc.Authenticate();

            Console.WriteLine(tpc.InstanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires an `https:` connection.

Comment: I've had trouble getting this to work - Apparently when you use your Microsoft Account credentials the supplied values will not work as expected.  To authenticate against VSO 2015 I had to enable "alternate credentials" so that I could change the username to a non-email-address format. After that this code worked fine.

Comment: agree with Volkirith. this doesn't work with VS2015 now need alternate credentials setup first before you can actually run it.

Comment: This is kind of an old thread, but if you go over SSL then try using the SimpleWebTokenCredential instead of the NetworkCredential and BasicAuthCredential.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some updates to authentication. For .NET apps we now recommend using [VSTS client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet). Another option is to use Azure Active Directory Libraries (ADAL). For more information and samples check out [VSTS's authentication documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication_guidance).