# TFS Api Crashes when a query is called on a project that is hosted on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, tfs, azure-devops

I have an **Asp.Net MVC** project that **fetches certain data from the TFS** (hosted on visualstudio.com) and visualizes it. I then **deploy the website to Windows Azure** (hosted on azurewebsites.com).

Fetching changesets, people, builds, source files, etc. works fine locally (via IIS) and on Azure. Fetching TestCases and WorkItems **fails on Azure**, but **works locally** (via IIS). I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

Unfortunately, I have no idea to overcome this issue. The only thing I found out was that in all cases that work on Azure with predefined queries provided by the API and in the case where it crashes (WorkItems & TestCases) I write a query and run it. Example:

```
 if (_connection.GetTeamProjectCollection() == null) return new List<ITestCase>();
 var testService = _connection.GetTeamProjectCollection().GetService<ITestManagementService>();
 var project = testService.GetTeamProject(_projectName);
 var query = "SELECT [Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + _projectName + "' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case'";
 var testCases = project.TestCases.Query(query); //TODO: works locally but crashes on Azure
 return testCases.ToList();
```

Did anyone have a similar experience? Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `NetworkCredential`  & `BasicAuthCredential  class`
link : [How to authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services with the new basic authentication from a .Net Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245776/how-to-authenticate-to-team-foundation-service-with-the-new-basic-authentication)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As written above, the authentication works fine and also fetching data for builds, people, changesets, etc. works. The only case where I get the mentioned error is with TestCases and WorkItems. The only difference I could find was that I run custom queries in those cases and predefined ones (via API) in the cases where it works. Any suggestions would be appreciated very much!