# Add files/folder to Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) using API from MVC application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to upload a file to Visual Studio Team Services using RestAPI from an MVC C# based application. But not able to get the how to upload or add a file or create a folder using api.

Can anyone please let me know what api method do I need to call to perform this action.

As per my understanding the files that we add in Team Services, via api we can call from Version Control Items (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items), from this api I understand that we can get the item and its metadata. But how to upload an file/folder?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Git** as source control, you can use [this API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pushes) to add, edit, rename, move, and delete files in a Git repository. You can either make changes in an existing branch or create a new one.

If you are using **TFVC** as source control, there is no related REST API can achieve for now. However you can use [Team Foundation version control commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) as a workaround, [Checkin command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/checkin-command) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I have found another way as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245776/how-to-authenticate-to-team-foundation-service-with-the-new-basic-authentication